# How can Windows Phone 8 's WebBrowser control to reset the scale?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Are there some APIs to get the WebBrowser control's current scale, like WebView's GetScale method in Android, I want to get the current scale and reset the current scale if user scale the page with finger?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no special property for that, but you can **try** the following

**To get current scale**

```
MyBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "'' + screen.deviceXDPI/screen.logicalXDPI" })
```

Based on [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

**To reset scale**

Use *InvokeScipt* as showed above to set zoom via viewport meta tag or [-ms-viewport rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (width: device-width or user-zoom: fixed; max-zoom: 1; min-zoom: 1;).

Comment: I found a suck workaround to reset the browser's scale.Decrease WebBrowser's height to a very small number, such as 10, after seconds, reset the WebBrowser's height,  amazingly, the scale has been reset